# getLatitude and getLongitude crashing on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am using Location code to get the Latitude and Longitude of the devices its working fine on the following devices:
HTC One M8
Moto X 2ndG
NexusP
One Plus 2

But it crashes in Samsung Galaxy S6

here is the location code I am using.

```
       public static ParseGeoPoint geoPointFromLocation(Location loc) {
            return new ParseGeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        }
    myLoc = (MainActivity.currentLocation == null) ? MainActivity.lastLocation : MainActivity.currentLocation;

around.setLocation(MainActivity.geoPointFromLocation(myLoc));
```

Logcat Added:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at io.wyntr.peepster.Activities.MainActivity.geoPointFromLocation(MainActivity.java:399)
                                                                     at io.wyntr.peepster.Activities.RecipientsActivity$2.onClick(RecipientsActivity.java:124)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Location Code used in the MainActivity:

```
boolean hasSetUpInitialLocation;

    public static Location lastLocation;
    public static Location currentLocation;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private static GoogleApiClient GoogleApiClient;
    // Milliseconds per second
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    // The update interval
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;

    // A fast interval ceiling
    private static final int FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS = 1;

    // Update interval in milliseconds
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // A fast ceiling of update intervals, used when the app is visible
    private static final long FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS;
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .coordinatorLayout);

        if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {

        } else {

            TSnackbar snackbar = TSnackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,"No Internet Connection",TSnackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }

        // Set the update interval
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            requestLocationPermissions();
        }

 if (checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        currentLocation = getLocation();
        try{startPeriodicUpdates();} catch (Exception e){
            requestLocationPermissions();
        }

    }

private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            return true;
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Display an error dialog
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Wyntr-Beta");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        snackbar = TSnackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout,"Connection Suspended",TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.show();
    }


    private void startPeriodicUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            requestLocationPermissions();
        }
        try{LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                GoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);}  catch(Exception e){
            requestLocationPermissions();
        }
    }

    private Location getLocation() {
        // If Google Play Services is available
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            // Get the current location
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                requestLocationPermissions();

            }
            return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect to the location services client
        GoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        GoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                snackbar = TSnackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Your Android Device is not Supported", TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    public static ParseGeoPoint geoPointFromLocation(Location loc) {
        return new ParseGeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    }
```

I have the location code. The PlayServices I am using has been deperecated but its working on the other devices. Its not working on the Samsung Galaxy Devices only.

Comment: How do you obtain the location? 
Could you provide more code... Your Location loc object maybe is null.

Comment: What is the android version for Samsung Galaxy S6 ?

Comment: @OmarHossam 6.0 all the devices I have listed above

Comment: @Rami Logcat Added

Comment: Can you post from where you call 'geoPointFromLocation'

Comment: @OmarHossam from mainactivity I have posted the code for the MainActivity please check

Comment: Your location is null and therefore `loc.getLatitude()` crashes with a `NullPointerException`. Also nowhere in your code you assign any value to `lastLocation`. Your location is null because `getLastLocation()` has returned null. This is a scenario which you must prepare for. The "last location" may well be unknown i.e. null and your code needs to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If your *Samsung S6* has been upgraded to **Android Marshmallow 6**, So i guess your problem would be permission problem, Please consider to ask for permission in runtime for Android 6 to enable location.

Please check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
this for how to ask for permission on the runtime

This link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous would be helpful to know the new kind of permissions.

Comment: I have accepted the Runtime Permission and all the devices listed above are 6.0 so they have runtime permission